# useEffect as Callback for useState has too many dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am re-writing a class component with React Hooks (because it's cleaner) but am facing an issue.  In my class component I have a callback function to `this.setState({B: "blah blah blah"}, () => {//do some function with state A})`, so that every time state x changed, I would use the new state value in conjunction with State B. When I try to implement the same functionality with React Hooks like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Use state A with state B in function
   myFunction();
}, [myFunction])

const myFunction = useCallback(() => {console.log(`${A} and ${B}`}, [A, B]);
```

I only want my function to run when state A changes -- not state B...however right now it re-renders any time state A or state B renders.

I've tried only including one dependency -- A -- in the useCallback [A] -- but the problem is then I get: React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'B'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: Have you tried `useEffect(() => { ... }, [A])` or `useEffect(() => { ... }, [A, B])`? I'm not sure exactly what the variables represent. Either way, you should paste _real_ code to avoid XY problem.

Comment: @Thank you I've tried only including one dependency -- A -- in the useCallback [A] -- but the problem is then I get: React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'B'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect is composed by two params

effect: A imperative function that can return a cleanup function;

deps: If present, effect will only activate if the values in the list change.

Got this information on Visual Studio Code tips

So if you want to activate the effect only when "A" changes, you should put "A" on deps.

```js
useEffect(() => {}, [A]);
```

Comment: But what about: React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'B'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using

```
}, [A])
```

as the only dependency and at the end of the function use a comment like this :

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

That will disable the missing dependency and give you the result that you want.
That usually works for me.

Answer (score 0):

`useState` allows you send a function into its params, like a cb, always this cb needs to return a new state to render
Example:

```
setState((state) => {
    /** 'state' in this moment represent the state without changes */
    /** You can do all that you need with 'state' */
    console.log(state)
    /** */
    return (newState)
  })
```

`useEffect` dont has any functions in this moment, y `useCallback` is not necesary

If you have a handleChange function, i can give you a example if your state contains personal data:

```
const [person, setPerson] useState({name: '', lastName: ''})

const handleChange = (newPerson) => {
  setPerson((person) => {
    /** 'person' in this moment represent the state without changes */
    /** You can do all that you need with 'person' */
    console.log(person)
    /** */
    return (newPerson)
  })
}
```